# How to write an Equation in R (papaja)?

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, equation, papaja

I'm trying to write this equation using the [papaja package](https://github.com/crsh/papaja):

```
\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
$$LogVolume_(dcr)=$\alpha$ +$\beta$DMonday+$\gamma$DTuesday+...+$\delta$DSaturday+ $\epsilon$ $$ 
\end{equation}
```

It is a basic regression model equation but I'm having issues when trying to knit to pdf. I wrote it according to [this article](https://www.calvin.edu/~rpruim/courses/s341/S17/from-class/MathinRmd.html)

I get the following error in the output:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.137 $$\LogVolume
                  _(dcr)=$\alpha$ +$\beta$DMonday+$\gamma$DTuesday+...+$\del...

Error: Failed to compile bbbb.tex. See https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. 
See bbbb.log for more info.
```

Can anyone help me understand where the problem is? Thank you very much!

Comment: does your equation begin `$$LogVolume` or `$$\LogVolume` ?  That is, are you including a back-slash in your input or not?

Comment: I want it to start with Log Volume, without any slash.

Comment: There might also be some issues with `$$` and begin/end equation, e.g. see https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/190

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to know for sure - it might matter whether you're trying to compile to HTML or PDF, for example, and what else is in your document - but this works for me in an HTML document:

```
\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
\textrm{LogVolume}_{dcr}=\alpha +\beta \cdot \textrm{DMonday}+ 
      \gamma \cdot \textrm{DTuesday} +...+\delta \cdot \textrm{DSaturday}+ \epsilon
\end{equation}
```

Basically, I eliminated unnecessary $s. (I also made your variables Roman rather than italic; used {} around your subscript; and added center-dots for multiplication.)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Given that you are using `papaja` and you might decide to render your document to a Word file at some point it, you may want to use `pandoc` syntax to declare equations:

```
$$
\textrm{LogVolume}_{dcr}=\alpha +\beta \cdot \textrm{DMonday}+ 
      \gamma \cdot \textrm{DTuesday} +...+\delta \cdot \textrm{DSaturday}+ \epsilon
$$
```

This should work regardless of the output format.